# Copying local object to vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a singleton class that holds a vector with data. My problem is that I want to add data to that vector using the standard push_back() method. I have an object I want to save in that vector but it's a local object (created in a method in another class). Obviously, at the end of this method the local variable would be deleted which is fine because I do a push_back() of that data to the vector.

Now, this works fine for as long the method didn't end. After it ends the data is gone. This seems weird because push_back() should be using the copy constructor right? Now, I tried to add the local variable to the vector by reference, by value, as a pointer and with the move constructor in C++11 but all those things don't seem to work.

So this is the setup of the problem class-wise:

- ConnectionManager (holds the vector)
- ClassA (which has a method with the  local typeX object)

So, in short, I want the object created in a method in ClassA to be available after that method but in the vector from the ConnectionManager class.

EDIT: Here's the typeX I'm talking about:

```
struct Connection
{
    SOCKET socket;
    PlayerData* pPlayerData;
};
```

socket is just your normal winsock SOCKET variable and PlayerData* is a custom object created with Google's ProtocolBuffer.

FURTHER EDIT:

This is how I create the data:

```
Predefined::Connection connTemp;
connTemp.socket = 0;
connTemp.pPlayerData = data;
MultiplayerData::GetInstance()->AddPlayerToGame(connTemp);
```

connTemp.pPlayerData is, to answer the question, a locally created variable but it's created as a pointer.

Comment: Can you show us the *problematic* type `typeX` ?

Comment: I added it to the main question

Comment: Does `pPlayerData` point to local variable ?

Comment: Who manages the lifetime of `PlayerData`?

Comment: I added some info about pPlayerData to my question

Comment: That should work as long as `data` is valid.

Comment: @Dries - So where did `data` come from?  Where/when is it created?  What is its lifetime?

Comment: Are you applying the Rule of Three/Five?

Comment: @Dries - So basically, you have a `vector<Connection>`?  If so, then your `Connection` struct doesn't follow the "Rule of Three", thus making operations on a `vector<Connection>` suspicious.  The vector will make copies, and making copies of that struct as it stands now can be faulty.

Comment: @Dries Also, are we to assume that `AddPlayerToGame()` is the `push_back` call on the `vector<Connection>`?

Comment: @Paul: I've never heard of Rule of Three. I will ook that up. data is created in the method (right above the code I added). And yes Paul, you can assume that as it only does that

Comment: @Dries - ok.  Also, you may actually want to use the data, but your current code in some way "deletes" this data (maybe not obvious, but does so in any event).  If this is the case, then maybe you should use a `std::shared_ptr<PlayerData>` instead of a `PlayerData*`.  If you're in the situation where your code is at odds as to "who is the last to own the data is the deleter", then shared_ptr is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks, I'll try that out and let you know if the vector keeps the data

Comment: @Paul: I changed everything that has PlayerData* to work with std::shared_ptr<PlayerData> but it still doesn't keep the data in the vector. I can add you to the repo so you can view the source if you still want to help?

Comment: @Dries - See my answer below.  Also, you need to make sure that `GetInstance` is correct.  Other than that, maybe you're doing something else in the `vector` to remove the entry.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is that you're creating the `PlayerData` data, and expecting to have the same data be still available after the function exits, it looks like you should use a type such as `std::shared_ptr<PlayerData>` instead of a naked `PlayerData*`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
//..
class PlayerData 
{
   int x, y, z;
   public:
     PlayerData(int a1, int a2, int a3) : x(a1), y(a2), z(a3) {}
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<PlayerData> PlayerDataPtr;

struct Connection
{
    SOCKET socket;
    PlayerDataPtr pPlayerData;
};

typedef std::vector<Connection> ConnectionVector;

void foo()
{
   auto data = std::make_shared<PlayerData>(1, 2, 3);  // create data dynamically
   //...
   Connection connTemp;
   connTemp.socket = 0;
   connTemp.pPlayerData = data;
   MultiplayerData::GetInstance()->AddPlayerToGame(connTemp);  // this does the push_back
   //...
}
```

Since `pPlayerData` is now a `shared_ptr`, those copies that `vector` will generate just bump up a reference count, and conversely, when those copies are destroyed, the reference count is decremented.  When the reference count reaches 0, then the `data` will indeed be deleted.

If you haven't called `reset` on the shared pointer, this is more or less, your guarantee that the `data` you created before the `push_back` was done will exist, as long as that entry in the vector wasn't removed.

Also, I edited the example to show a simpler `PlayerData` class.  Note how `make_shared` is used.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. I tried it but I get an error on this line: `auto data = std::make_shared<PlayerData>(message.add_playerdata());` It says: `'PlayerData::PlayerData(const PlayerData &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PlayerData *' to 'const PlayerData &'`

Comment: @Dries - You need to show what `message.add_playerdata()` returns.  Second, the parameters to `make_shared` are the parameters you need to construct a `PlayerData`.  So you're saying that to construct a `PlayerData` you need to pass a pointer to a `PlayerData`?  That sounds confusing, and possibly the reason why you're losing track of data.  Look at my edited code above.

Comment: the thing is that I need to call `message.add_playerdata()` as it is because it's generated by ProtocolBuffer. it returns a `PlayerData*`. That return value is added to `auto data` which makes it,obviously, ready to be filled in. This is just how ProtocolBuffer works. I added a `*` in front of `message.add_playerdata()` and now it compiles. I'll let you know what it does. EDIT: well, that didn't work

Comment: I changed the line to this: `shared_ptr<PlayerData> data(message.add_playerdata());` but it's still losing the data in it after I add it to the vector and the method ends. Also, it's not a problem with the singleton, I checked it's value and it's the same in all places

Comment: It's definitely a problem with the PlayerData object in the struct since the socket value is stored correctly

Comment: Ok... I figured it out. I changed the PlayerData object in the Connection struct to a "normal" object, so not a pointer. I can still create a pointer in my other code and then fill in the struct with the data the pointer is referencing to.

Answer (score 1):

Struct Connection will indeed be copied into the vector, so you don't need to worry about end of its lifetime. pPlayerData however needs to point into a memory allocated with new and owned by somebody.

```
connTemp.pPlayerData = data;
```

Where does the 'data' come from - generated locally?
The 'data' needs to be allocated by 'new' at some point.

If the "data" are all unique, consider using auto_ptr or unique_ptr for the type of pPlayerData member - C++ doesn't automatically manage standard pointers. If they're not unique, use shared_ptr or intrusive_ptr - can start with shared and retrofit intrusive later.